# Setting a global seed for mimesis

Tags: python, faker

In the mimesis documentation/code, I see that the `BaseProvider` and thus all providers have a `seed` kwarg. The documentation on it is sparse (as far as I can find), but it looks like as with faker, it sets the randomizer seed, thus if I want to replicate a particular set of random data, I could provide the same seed.

That said, I can't find how to set a global seed for mimesis. With faker, I can just do

```
Faker.seed(random_seed)
```

but I don't see an equivalent for mimesis. I'm also trying to use it with factory boy, and with `mimesis_factory`, it's even more confusing.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but it does seem like there's a `seed` kwarg as you said and that that argument can be passed to the generic `Field` object.  Example: `Field(locale=Locale.EN, seed=10)`.  The same is true for the specific field times e.g. `Person`.  Could you provide some example code for what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on how you are using mimesis but generally speaking you initialize the objects with the seed.  Any generated data will be the same each time.

```py
from mimesis import Generic, Field, Person

seed = 123
gen = Generic(Locale.EN, seed=seed)
field = Field(Locale.EN, seed=seed)
person = Person(Locale.EN, seed=seed)
```

There is also the ability to call `.reseed(seed)` which has the affect of starting the data generation over.

```py
seed = 123
gen = Generic(Locale.EN, seed=seed)
print(gen.person.full_name())
print(gen.person.full_name())
gen.reseed(seed)
print(gen.person.full_name())
print(gen.person.full_name())

# output
Ira Boyd
Kerstin Bryant
Ira Boyd
Kerstin Bryant
```

Comment: Yah, as I put in the question, every provider has the seed kwarg. I was hoping there was some way to provide a global seed so I didn't need to pass the same kwarg to every provider.

Comment: That would be where I would suggest just using  `Generic`, which contains all the providers.  `Faker` and `Generic` are similar at that point.  So you can call `gen.persion.full_name()` rather than `person.full_name()`